# How do I obtain Chrysoidine from Benzene?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds

[image]

So, basically I can convert Benzene to Phenol using Dow's synthesis process and then use $\ce{NH3}$, $\ce{ZnCl2}$, $\ce{HNO2}$, $\ce{NaNO2}$ under 0-5 °C controlled temperature and convert the phenol to Diazonium Chloride Salt. Then with Coupling Reaction, I can convert the Diazonium Chloride to Aniline Yellow. But, Chrysoidine has another $\ce{-NH2}$ group attached to the Ortho position. So, an explanation would be greatly appreciated as to how to obtain Chrysoidine from there on.

Comment: why go via the phenol? Easier surely to nitrate benzene then reduce to aniline.

Comment: @Waylander Yes, I know that pathway to Aniline as well. However, I wanted to know whether Aniline Yellow, upon reacting with Nitric Acid and then being reduced by Sn and HCl, yields Chrysoidine. Or will the -NO2 group just get attached to the Meta position?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think aniline yellow is likely to nitrate ortho to the aniline giving you the wrong structure. Also the Sn/HCl reduction may well reduce the azo double bond.

Here is a route from benzene.
From benzene a simple nitration gives nitrobenzene. Divide your nitrobenzene, reduce one portion to aniline by hydrogenation over Pd or Pt catalyst. Nitrate the second portion to 1,3-dinitrobenzene [procedure here](https://labmonk.com/synthesis-of-m-dinitrobenzene-from-nitrobenzene). Reduce the 1,3-dinitrobenzene by hydrogenation over Pd or Pt catalyst to give m-phenylenediamine. Diazotise your aniline to the diazonium and react this with the phenylenediamine. This route was used industrially to prepare Chrysoidine in the 19th century [reference here](https://www.si.edu/mci/downloads/reports/IESD-CCDP1991.pdf).

Comment: My gratitude, sir. This helped a lot. :D

Comment: Please accept the answer if you are happy with it.